# Issue in retrieve Post from Facebook account using c#

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook Graph API to retrieve post information of user from Facebook profile.

i am writing `"/me/feed?fields=id"` in Graph API Explorer for retrieve post of user, it gives me list of id.

but when i try to do same thing from code in c# .net than it gives me different list of ids.

my code is like

```
dynamic result = client.Get("me/feed?fields=id");
```

i have did same thing in both but both gives me different result.
can any tell me why this happen ? where i am wrong ?

Thank you